# smtp not working on 1and1

Tags: email, cakephp

I'm using 1and1 server to host my CakePHP 3.2 application

This is how, I have configured email component on CakePHP

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'noreply@mywebsite.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

But this is not working and no email is sent and gives `Connection Time out` after 30 seconds.

From 1and1 email configuration page. It says

```
Outgoing port (TLS must be activated)
```

How to enable/configure TLS in CakePHP ?

> Edit 2

the error stack shows 
**SmtpTransport.php**

```
protected function _connect()
{
    $this->_generateSocket();
    if (!$this->_socket->connect()) {     // marked this line
       throw new SocketException('Unable to connect to SMTP server.');
    }
    $this->_smtpSend(null, '220');
```

**Action to send email**

```
public function sendEmail($user_id = null, $email_id = null, $hash = null, $request = null)
{
    switch($request) {
      case 'register' : $subject = 'Account Confirmation';
                        $message = 'You have successfully registered. Click below link to verify it http://website.com/sellers/verify/'.$email_id.'/'.$hash;
        break;
    }

    $email = new Email('default');
    if ($email->from(['anujsharma9196@gmail.com' => 'Argo Systems'])
          ->to((string)$email_id)
          ->subject($subject)
          ->send($message)) {

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

and calling this function from same controller by

```
$this->sendEmail($user->id, $user->email, $hash, 'register');
```

Comment: There is a parameter called 'tls' in your array, didn't you notice it?

Comment: what is inside the 'url' parameter? I think that the url parameter is to be used instead of the others. Don't know if url overwrite the others or the opposite

Comment: arilia, see `Edit 2`. I'm passing nothing in the url instead calling function from inside of the same controller. Same is working fine with localhost server. The problem has arrived since uploaded application to hosting server

Comment: from the [**api**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Mailer.Email.html#1225-1273) seems that the url overwrites the other parameters

Comment: I mean. what inside `env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null)`?

Comment: How to find what is inside `env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null)` I haven't modified anything except `host, port, username and password` in the component.

Comment: simply debug it somewhere in your application

Comment: I debugged `debug(env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null));` and `debug(env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL'));` in controller and both gives `null`

Comment: so it does not affect you configuration, you can remove it, if you want

Comment: removing `url` has no effect to the error

Comment: did you read [**this**](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/send-e-mails-using-php-a657019.html) tutorial? Seems that you don't need to pass through the smtp server. Just setup a simple 'className' => 'Mail' transporter without any other parameter and it should work

Comment: Thanks @arilia it means I can't use SMTP on this server and have to stick with php mail function

Comment: no, it means that if you want you can avoid using Smtp and tell cake to use  mail internally setting the proper Transport (see my answer). You can still use cake Email class. Probabbly you can use smtp too but I can't find any reference on how to configure it inside PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [**manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports) (bold is mine)

> You can configure SSL SMTP servers, like Gmail. To do so, put the ssl:// prefix in the host and configure the port value accordingly. **You can also enable TLS SMTP using the tls option**:

so just set

```
'tls' => true
```

in your configuration array and try if it works

**Edit**

following [**this**](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/send-e-mails-using-php-a657019.html) page I found that you don't even need to use the `Smtp` transporter

just use a simple `Mail` transporter this way

```
'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail'
]
```

> There is no need to supply a username, password, or specify which mail server should be used to send the mail since this information is already contained in PHP variables.

try that!

Comment: i had noticed `tls` and already set `true`. I was missing `ssl://`. Added it and now host is like `host => 'ssl://smtp.1and1.com` but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
I used below configuration in system for mail using gmail. it work fine. you just try with your server.

 'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'SMTP',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 100,
            'username' => 'example@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'exmple123',
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],

Check with your port and host.Hope fully it will works

Try 

Thanks
```

Comment: why defining two `className` ?

Comment: you are correct. I was also using the same thing and was working fine on my localhost. After uploading application on 1and1 host, its not working

Comment: I have one solution, don't use emailTranports configuration, make it remain as it like default cakephp and then use server smtp mail server.

Comment: Use below code :  $email = new Email('default');
        $email->from([$from_email => 'example@gmail.com'])
                ->to($to)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->send($content);
        return $email;